# Radio stream listen in HTML5 Audio element doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, html5-audio

I have a radio stream working fine in browsers and Android phones, but when I try to listen on an iPhone it seems not to work. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

Html:

```
<audio id='player' controls="controls" style="display: none">
 <source src="http://167.114.116.151:8010/;listen.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

JavaScript:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var getaudio = $('#player')[0];

    $("#volume").val(getaudio.volume*100);
    $('#stop').hide();
    $('#mute').hide();


    $('#play').click(function(){
            //getaudio.play();
            document.getElementById("player").play();
            $('#play').hide();
            $('#stop').show();
    });
    $('#stop').click(function(){
        getaudio.pause();
        $('#play').show();
        $('#stop').hide();
    });
    $('.audio').click(function(){
        if (getaudio.muted) {
            getaudio.muted= false;
            $('#mute').hide();
            $('#audio').show();
        }else{
            getaudio.muted= true;
            $('#mute').show();
            $('#audio').hide();
        }
    });
    $("#volume").bind("change", function() {
        getaudio.volume = $(this).val()/100;
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the semi-colon in the URL meant to be there?

Comment: Its work fine in others platform with semi-colon there. Without it it doesnt work.